# base64_encode a JPG in PHP gives incompatible string

Tags: php, encoding, base64

I have to send a JPG file via XML and tried to use the base64_encode-function of PHP.

The server doesn't accept the file. So I did some research and found an online encoder (http://base64.wutils.com/encoding-online/) which gives a totally different string as compared to the function-output and it works!!!

Happy I am to have found the cause but I need a solution ;-) I am not too knowledgeable about the base64-encoding standard to understand what is the root cause of the difference.

I am pasting the first and last characters of the results, maybe that helps:

base64_encoding from PHP (doesn't work): "ZGF0YTppbWFnZS9qcGVnO2Jhc2U2NCwvOWovNEFBUVNrWkpSZ0FCQVFFQVl...GRkFCUlJSUUFVVVVVQUZGRkZBQlJSUlFBVVVVVUFGRkZGQUgvOWs9"

http://base64.wutils.com/encoding-online/ (works):
"/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD//gA7Q1JF...KKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigD/2Q=="

Comment: you need to show us some code, what you have tried, etc.

Comment: You'll have to provide a lot more detail about *what exactly you're doing*, both in your PHP code and how exactly you're using that online encoder. As it stands there's nothing really we can say about anything except *you've probably been doing it wrong.*

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by myself: I used a Bundle (Gregwar Image Bundle) to retrieve and encode the file instead of the 'original' PHP-function. Now that I use the PHP-function it works fine.

Anyways. If someone has a clue how these different file results might come up - I'd be very interested ;-)

Thanks!
Steffen